# How to turn off the mesh in THREE.MeshBasicMaterial

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, three.js

I'm using THREE.js to draw an image and its reflection. How do I turn off the mesh that appears in the reflection? It seems to only happen when I'm altering the alpha channel.

```
    imageReflection = document.createElement('canvas');
    imageReflection.width = 480;
    imageReflection.height = 204;

    imageReflectionContext = imageReflection.getContext('2d');
    imageReflectionContext.fillStyle = '#000000';
    imageReflectionContext.fillRect(0, 0, 480, 204);

    textureReflection = new THREE.Texture(imageReflection);
    var materialReflection = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:textureReflection, side:THREE.BackSide, transparent:true, overdraw:0.5});
```

[image]